# Products Not Showing Under Product Category in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, content-management-system

I am having a wordpress site here [Link To Website](http://kanchancollections.com) . Products are showing everywhere in latest products , shop but when i click on Category on Sidebar of website like Earrings no products shown under it but in reality products exist in this category what could be possible problem and solution

Stock Management is Disabled in Woocommerce settings

It shows this instead of showing product

```
<p class="woocommerce-info">No products were found matching your selection.</p>
```

This is Page for one of my Product Categories . It is having 3 products in it but showing nothing
http://www.kanchancollections.com/product-category/baju-band/

My Woocommerce Settings Screenshot is below -
[image: Woocommerce Settings Page]

**Update:**
As Stated in one of answers i am clerifying I have set my product categories you can see in screenshot below
[image: Product Category of Product]

Comment: Could you please provide your full code?

Comment: @GauravJariwala what code you need

Comment: Code, that you have tried to display products...may be in archive-product.php or single-products.php

Answer (score 4):

If you never got the answer.  Go to all products, and to quick edit. Make sure your visibility setting is set to "catalog" or "search & catalog."

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might have marked the categories as 'categories' rather than 'product categories'

Add earrings as a 'product category' to a product and see if it shows up.

Comment: It is already a product category see my updated pic in question

Comment: Its a little difficult to figure out without more information. Did anything pop up in the debug log ? The only other thing I can think of is to check Catalog visibility for the product to make sure its set to "Catalog/Search"

Answer (score 1):

@user5493185

Like you I've had same problem, The solution to this is Visit All product page - Select the product that is not showing in your desired category - Select quick edit - And Choose product in stock and update it.

Reload your page and you'll see the product inside product category.
As of now this is working.

Do check and let me know.

Comment: This worked for me as well! But wondering why this has happened. Any idea?

Comment: I don't know the reason, It's just that I was just trying to update the page with some lucky tweaks it and it worked. Well you can up vote my answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone reading this still has the same issue I found an easy solution that worked for me. Just delete the category and remake it. Took me less than two minutes and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent whole day trying to figure out what was the problem. Go to Products -> Categories -> Edit category and set 'Display type' to 'Default' This helped me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31097081)